# How to send FB custom payload from webhook to dialogflow v2 then to FB server?

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialogflow-es

How to send FB custom payload from webhook to dialogflow v2 then to FB server?

I want to send below FB response JSON object from webhook to dialogflow server then it will send to FB server. But unable to find build in method of dialogflow v2 to send response object from webhook to dialogflow then to FB messenger user.

Response Object :-
{
    "fulfillmentText": "displayed&spoken response",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
            "text": [
                "text response"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "source": "example.com",
    "payload": {
        "facebook": {
            "text": "Hello, Facebook!"
        }
    },
    "outputContexts": [
        {
            "name": "projects/${PROJECT_ID}/agent/sessions/${SESSION_ID}/contexts/context name",
            "lifespanCount": 5,
            "parameters": {
                "param": "param value"
            }
        }
    ],
    "followupEventInput": {
        "name": "event name",
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "parameters": {
            "param": "param value"
        }
    }
}

the above FB response object taken from dialogflow v2 documentation but unable to find build in method to send that response object from webhook to dialogflow then to FB messenger.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?